# Adobe Edge Animate loop code

Tags: adobe-edge

I'm trying to loop some code in Adobe Edge Animate, but it doesn't seem to work after the frst run.
The function makes a fly visible on my stage, if you click the fly it gets hidden (that code is handled in the fly symbol itself). The following code shows the fly once, and it only dissapears after about 10 clicks, and it doesn't return.

```
sym.$("Fly2").hide();
MakeFlies();

function FlyMaker() {
    setTimeout(MakeFlies(),15000);
}




function MakeFlies() {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*3000)+1000;
    setTimeout(function(){
    sym.$("Fly2").show();
    },rand);


    FlyMaker();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One error I can see in your code is that you are calling:

```
setTimeout(MakeFlies(), 15000);
```

setTimeout takes a function as argument. Here you are executing the function right away (it does not wait timeout).

Write something like:

```
// Assign function a name
var makeFlies = function () {..}
// Pass function variable as argument. Will be executed after 15 seconds
setTimeout(makeFlies, 15000);
```

You can call the function as usual with () brackets

```
// call function and execute it now
makeFlies();
```